# 1.find line of curvature, asymptotic curve and geodesic curve of the unit sphere?

Tags: differential-geometry

### 1.find line of curvature, asymptotic curve and geodesic curve of the unit sphere?

-Local parameterization: $$r(u,v)=O+\cos{v}.\vec{e(u)}+\sin(v)\vec{k}$$
then we can compute $$\begin{split}\quad \vec{n\circ r}&=\cos v.\vec{e(u)}+\sin v.\vec{k}\\E&=\vec{r'_u}.\vec{r'_u}={\cos^2{v}}\\F&=\vec{r'_u}.\vec{r'_v}=0\\G&=\vec{r'_v}.\vec{r'_v=1}\\L&={-\cos^2{v}}\\M&=0\\N&=-1\end{split}$$
then the Principal curve is the following:$$(MG-NF)dv^2-(LG-NE)dudv+(LF-ME)Du^2=0$$
then we get  $0=0$ What can we conclude?

-The asymptotic curve follows: $$\begin{split}Ldu^2+2Mdudv+Ndv^2&=0\\\cos^2vdu^2+dv^2&=0\end{split}$$

then the solution of the differential equation is: $$u-v^2/2+\ln|\cos v|=c$$
Is this the asymptotic curve of the unit sphere?

-The  **geodesic** curvature is my remaining problem, I have no idea where to start?
hope the help from you all!

Answer (score 1):

- Lines of curvature. You computation is correct. This is because the first and second fundamental forms are proportional (umbilical points). At umbilical points there is no preferred basis of principal
  directions, and thus it makes sense that the only solution of the differential equation for the line of curvature is $v^{'}(t) u^{'}(t)$ = 0, i.e. u and v are constant. In conclusion all points on the sphere are umbilics, and since the principal directions are undetermined at all points all curves on the sphere may be taken as lines of curvature.
- Asymptotic curves.
  Asymptotic curves are those curves which travel in directions of zero normal curvature. The solution of the equation you wrote implies that all asymptotic curves are imaginary curves. Forgetting for a moment the restriction to real curve only, we find the integral of the equation:
  \begin{equation}
  \big(\frac{v^{'}(t)}{\cos{v(t)}}\big)^2 = - u'^{2}(t)
  \end{equation}
  in the form
  \begin{equation}
  \tan\big(\frac{v}{2}+\frac{\pi}{4}\big)= c e^{\pm j u}
  \end{equation}
  where c is the integration constant and $j=\sqrt{-1}$.
- In general, given a curve $\gamma(t)$ whose trace lies on a surface, the tangential component of $\gamma^{''}(t)$ defines the geodesic curvature, which depends only on the first fundamental form. The first fundamental form of a surface can be determined entirely by measurements within the surface and do not depend on any quantities outside
  the surface such as the normal vector. Therefore, all quantities of the theory of surfaces that are expressible in terms of the first fundamental form alone can be determined by measurements within the surface. The geodesic curvature is often expressed in term of the Christoffel symbols $\Gamma_{i j}^k$. In the case of the sphere the coefficient F of the first fundamental form is zero, i.e. you have an orthogonal coordinate system. Orthogonal coordinates never have off-diagonal terms in their metric tensor.
  In such a case the geodesic curvature simplifies to:
  \begin{equation}
  s'^{3} k_g=\sqrt{E G} \big(-\frac{E_v}{2G} u'^{3}+ \big(\frac{G_u}{G}-\frac{E_u}{2 E}\big) u'^{2} v'+ \big(\frac{G_v}{2G}-\frac{E_v}{E}\big) u' v'^{2}+ \frac{G_u}{2 E}v'^{3}+ u'v''-u'' v' \big)
  \end{equation}
  where s is the arc length. Since only G is constant and equal to one and E depends on v only the above formula reduces to:
  \begin{equation}
  s'^{3} k_g=\sqrt{E} \big(-\frac{E_v}{2}u'^{3}-\frac{E_v}{E} u' v'^{2}+ u'v''-u'' v'\big)
  \end{equation}
  where $E_v=-\sin(2 v)$ we have
  \begin{equation}
  s'^{3} k_g= |\cos(v)|\big(\frac{1}{2} \sin(2 v) u'^{3}+2 \tan(v) u' v'^{2}+ u'v''-u'' v'\big)
  \end{equation}